# How do you organize recording session files?

Tags: recording, session-organization

For the past year or so I've been recording jam sessions on my new (and growing) modular setup. I don't do it *every* night, but when I do I usually record 3 or 4 sessions.

So... without actually counting, I'd guess I have somewhere between 500 and 1000 recording sessions from the last year. It's ridiculous.

Some of the recordings are ok, but need some edits. Some are excellent, ready fr release. Some long sessions have the potential to become multiple "tracks" but require more work. Many sessions aren't worth keeping.

Because it's easier to record more music than it is to review and organize what I've already got, the problem just keeps getting worse.

SO

I want to come up with a VERY SIMPLE method for reviewing my recordings and sorting them out. I need a method that's simple so that it's easy to remember, easy to remain consistent, and hopefully, easy enough to be a fun thing I'll actually do occasionally.

I'm wondering if anyone has suggestions. Curious to hear how other people deal with this type of situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create 3 folders:

- ready for release
- needs editing
- no good

Listen to each recording once and move the files to one of these folders.

If 'Ready for release' contains more than 100 sessions, delete 'Needs editing' and 'No good' immediately. If it's less than 100, just delete 'No good'.

In the future, don't keep everything. You'll usually know right away when a session's no good, so delete it right away.

PS read up a bit on 'hoarding'.

Comment: These are great points, thank you!